MySQL Replication, Master Slave- Last_SQL_Errno: 1062, Worker 1 failed executing transaction 'ANONYMOUS' at source log mysql-bin
My mysql replication (master - slave) is failing with following error:

Last_SQL_Errno: 1062


Last_SQL_Error: Coordinator stopped because there were error(s) in the worker(s). The most recent failure being: Worker 1 failed
executing transaction 'ANONYMOUS' at source log mysql-bin.000115,
end_log_pos 468117420. See error log and/or
performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker table for more
details about this failure or others, if any.

I checked the bin log file and I see following

2024-12-03T21:48:34.088063Z 7 [ERROR] [MY-010584] [Repl] Replica SQL
for channel '': Worker 1 failed executing transaction 'ANONYMOUS' at
source log mysql-bin.000123, end_log_pos 515; Could not execute
Write_rows event on table mydb.wp_options; Duplicate entry
'_transient_jetpack_update_remote_package_last_query' for key
'wp_options.option_name', Error_code: 1062; handler error
HA_ERR_FOUND_DUPP_KEY; the event's source log mysql-bin.000123,
end_log_pos 515, Error_code: MY-001062


2024-12-03T21:48:34.088873Z 6 [ERROR] [MY-010586] [Repl] Error running query, replica SQL thread
aborted. Fix the problem, and restart the replica SQL thread with
"START REPLICA". We stopped at log 'mysql-bin.000123' position 157

The problematic database is a WordPress database.
How do I fix it and also avoid this happening in the future as I've many wordPress databases and I'll have more in the future.

Usually it shouldn't happen. Have you made direct insert into the slave ? Verify _transient_jetpack_update_remote_package_last_query on * mydb.wp_options* on both slave and master

No, I haven't made any insert. Slave was rebooted and then it lost sync.
